# Array, how to transfer some of the value to the first value? (Illustration provided)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Picture below shows my array. As you can see at the marked yellow boxes, i wanted these value transfer to the first value. Which is all these value have the same furniture_id marked with red circle. Is it possible to do these?

[image: my array]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-merge I think there will be something you can use if you read the docs

Comment: i just look at the documentation...by using the merge, it overwrites the value that contain the same key name

Comment: Just use another array variable and after that go through a loop of this array and push these two values in new array. so new array will contain furniture_id, cust_id, furniture date and an array with multiple furniture_type & price.

Comment: wow...not sure why this question is downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple laravel thing to do is:

```
$result = collect($array)->groupBy("furniture_id")
            ->map(function ($group) {
                   return collect($group)
                          ->reduce(function ($carry, $groupItemObject) {
                               $groupItem = (array) $groupItemObject;
                               if ($carry == null) {
                                   $carry = array_only($groupItem, ["furniture_id", "furniture_date", "cust_id"]) + [ "price_type" => [ ] ]; //Initial
                               } 
                               $carry["price_type"][] = array_only($groupItem, [ "price", "furniture_type" ]);
                               return $carry;
                         });
            });
```

What this does is first groups everything by the furniture_id, then it maps the groups to a single entry that groups price and type only.

Comment: not sure what the code does, but i tried your codes and have this error "array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array"

Comment: Try the edit. What this does is use many collection operations like groupBy map and reduce. The idea is to group by the id them map each group to a reduced form

Comment: oh my...this works perfectly, you gave me straight forward answer with a great explanations...i might experiment a bit using this method, thank you very much!